# How to create log file using logback.xml outside of JAR?

Tags: java, jar, logback

I am facing problems while creating log files outside JAR.

```
Project Structure

./ – the root of my project
|__ api.jar ( logback.xml inside this jar )
|__ /logs
    |__ ( log files need to be generated )
```

I have the following configuration in logback.xml.

```
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>./logs/filename.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
</configuration>
```

The log files are not generated inside the logs folder which is under my project root folder.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Have you tried putting it simply in the same folder as api.jar instead of inside the jar? Seems to me that putting it inside the jar makes not too much sense - you won't be able to edit it at runtime ...

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. I just don't need to edit logback.xml at runtime.  Let me try and i'll come back.

Comment: How do you run your application? It might be generated in the folder you are running in.

Comment: I am running from shell script file

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to run my program with the example you posted, and it generated the log all right. There are many ways how how it can go wrong in your case. I have some  suggestions.

- Are you sure you are running your application from your project root? If not, the log file will be created elsewhere.

What do you have on your classpath?

- If there is logback.groovy or logback-test.xml anywhere on the classpath, it will take precedence and your logback.xml will be ignored.
- Same for another logback.xml that is found sooner than yours.